# Change part of the link depends of environment in typescript

Tags: angular, spring, typescript, kubernetes, configmap

I would like to add the link to some field and part of that link should differ depends on the used environment. Lets say that I have dev and prod environment.

- Link for dev should looks like: "*https://dev.mytest.com*"
- Link for prod should looks like: "*https://prod.mytest.com*"

I think that I should somehow put these variables to application.yaml (maybe kubernetes here would be helpful?) but I don't know how to access these variables in typescript file. I'm using spring in my project with the application.yaml file.
Could you give me some tips how I should achieve that or sent a link for helpful articles?

Answer (score 3):

You can use some files, usually called `environment.[xyz].ts`, to achieve some configuration depending on the type of build configured in your `angular.json` file.

For more informations: https://angular.io/guide/build

=== EDIT ===

If you need it to be a runtime configuration, you can create a JSON file into `src/assets/`, retrieve it and parse it with a service by making a simple http call, like: this.http.get('/assets/xyz.json') and storing the configuration inside the service.

To be sure that when you will use this service (via injection) the configuration will be already loaded, you can set its load configuration fuction to be executed on app startup with the `APP_INITIALIZER` DI token.

[This tutorial](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-runtime-configuration/) explains in details what I'm suggesting.

Comment: It helpful however it's not exactly what I want. Application is hosted on Kubernetes and it is possible that in future there will be some new environment stage ( for example: "http:s//test.mytest.com". And what I want to achieve to have this environment from outside (maybe some configmap) or by application.yaml but I don't know how to do it and i'm looking for some articles which can help me with that

Comment: Your app cannot get information from kubernetes. I think, the best you can do, is using an initContainer that will replace the environment.ts content with the one from the configmap.